# Can I replace a disk in btrfs raid1 without a reboot?

Tags: linux, btrfs

I am trying to understand how btrfs raid1 mode behaves when you take out one disk and put it back (odroid hc4 is an example device)

Here is what I have before the test:

```
Label: none  uuid: f85fb0ab-e643-4266-9f61-0f6e4980b871
    Total devices 2 FS bytes used 2.35GiB
    devid    1 size 111.79GiB used 9.03GiB path /dev/sdb
    devid    2 size 1.82TiB used 9.03GiB path /dev/sda
```

then I detach /dev/sda disk, dmesg shows this:

```
[158763.932162] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[158769.474056] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[158774.849753] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[158774.849775] ata1.00: disabled
[158774.849814] ata1.00: detaching (SCSI 0:0:0:0)
[158774.851067] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[158774.851161] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x04 driverbyte=0x00
[158774.851168] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[158774.851190] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Start/Stop Unit failed: Result: hostbyte=0x04 driverbyte=0x00
[158784.777808] BTRFS error (device sdb): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 9, rd 0, flush 1, corrupt 0, gen 0
[158784.778204] BTRFS error (device sdb): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 10, rd 0, flush 1, corrupt 0, gen 0
[158784.778716] BTRFS error (device sdb): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 11, rd 0, flush 1, corrupt 0, gen 0
[158784.779232] BTRFS error (device sdb): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 12, rd 0, flush 1, corrupt 0, gen 0
[158784.779505] BTRFS error (device sdb): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 13, rd 0, flush 1, corrupt 0, gen 0
[158784.782423] BTRFS error (device sdb): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 13, rd 0, flush 2, corrupt 0, gen 0
[158784.782651] BTRFS warning (device sdb): lost page write due to IO error on /dev/sda (-5)
[158784.782660] BTRFS error (device sdb): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 14, rd 0, flush 2, corrupt 0, gen 0
[158784.782762] BTRFS warning (device sdb): lost page write due to IO error on /dev/sda (-5)
[158784.782767] BTRFS error (device sdb): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 15, rd 0, flush 2, corrupt 0, gen 0
[158784.782864] BTRFS warning (device sdb): lost page write due to IO error on /dev/sda (-5)
[158784.782869] BTRFS error (device sdb): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 16, rd 0, flush 2, corrupt 0, gen 0
[158784.784112] BTRFS error (device sdb): error writing primary super block to device 2
[158788.810744] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[158788.814057] ata1.00: ATA-10: CT2000BX500SSD1, M6CR030, max UDMA/133
[158788.814064] ata1.00: 3907029168 sectors, multi 1: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32), AA
[158788.824662] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[158788.824934] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      CT2000BX500SSD1  030  PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[158788.825550] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[158788.825726] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdc] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[158788.825760] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[158788.825766] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[158788.825812] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[158788.863902] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[158788.884759] BTRFS warning: duplicate device /dev/sdc devid 2 generation 48028 scanned by systemd-udevd (5758)
[158789.894806] BTRFS error (device sdb): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 17, rd 0, flush 2, corrupt 0, gen 0
[158820.615643] BTRFS error (device sdb): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 18, rd 0, flush 2, corrupt 0, gen 0
[158820.616144] BTRFS error (device sdb): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 19, rd 0, flush 2, corrupt 0, gen 0
[158820.616585] BTRFS error (device sdb): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 20, rd 0, flush 2, corrupt 0, gen 0
[158820.617080] BTRFS error (device sdb): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 21, rd 0, flush 2, corrupt 0, gen 0
[158820.617353] BTRFS error (device sdb): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 22, rd 0, flush 2, corrupt 0, gen 0
[158820.617558] BTRFS error (device sdb): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 23, rd 0, flush 2, corrupt 0, gen 0
[158820.620575] BTRFS error (device sdb): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 23, rd 0, flush 3, corrupt 0, gen 0
[158820.620791] BTRFS warning (device sdb): lost page write due to IO error on /dev/sda (-5)
[158820.620799] BTRFS error (device sdb): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 24, rd 0, flush 3, corrupt 0, gen 0
[158820.620896] BTRFS warning (device sdb): lost page write due to IO error on /dev/sda (-5)
[158820.620901] BTRFS error (device sdb): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 25, rd 0, flush 3, corrupt 0, gen 0
[158820.621128] BTRFS warning (device sdb): lost page write due to IO error on /dev/sda (-5)
[158820.621237] BTRFS error (device sdb): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 26, rd 0, flush 3, corrupt 0, gen 0
[158820.622271] BTRFS error (device sdb): error writing primary super block to device 2
[158830.852513] BTRFS error (device sdb): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 27, rd 0, flush 3, corrupt 0, gen 0
```

then I attach it back and it appears as /dev/sdc this time.

If I try to replace it I get various errors:

```
# btrfs replace start 2 /dev/sdc /mnt
/dev/sdc appears to contain an existing filesystem (btrfs).
ERROR: use the -f option to force overwrite of /dev/sdc
```

```
# btrfs replace start 2 /dev/sdc /mnt -f
ERROR: /dev/sdc is mounted
```

But if I reboot the device everything goes back to normal.

Comment: you need to fail the drive first and then replace it regularly

Comment: How do I fail the device?

Comment: i found a similar like [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334228/btrfs-raid1-how-to-replace-a-disk-drive-that-is-physically-no-more-there) on unix-stackexchange

Comment: That question is about read-only state of a new device and an old linux kernel (4.4) I am on 5.11 also they moved to mdadm in the end. One of the comments mentioning that you better use disk uuid to build raid, I will try that hoping it will reduce dependency on device names changing in runtime in my case.

Comment: the way to failure is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer the "why" but I think it has something to do with btrfs still knowing that is the same device you are replacing and refusing to do so.

The only way I could resolve this issue was by wiping the fs from the drive prior to replacing.  I was also not able to get my drive to re-enumerate properly when hot-swapping, so had to reboot to get the drive to enumerate where I wanted.

```
$ sudo btrfs replace start -f 1 /dev/sdc/mnt/tmpbtrfs
ERROR: /dev/sdc is mounted
$ sudo wipefs -a /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc: 8 bytes were erased at offset 0x00010040 (btrfs): 5f 42 48 52 66 53 5f 4d
$ sudo btrfs replace start -f 1 /dev/sdc /mnt/tmpbtrfs
Started on 12.Aug 10:31:24, finished on 12.Aug 10:47:27, 0 write errs, 0 uncorr. read errs
```

Since I had such a hard time finding info on how to swap out a perfectly good btrfs raid1 disk I figured I'd write it down.

Here are the steps that worked for me when performing an in-place upgrade of a functioning drive in a btrfs raid1 array.

1. Balance array to correct profile
2. Add `,noauto` to btrfs line in /etc/fstab
3. Shutdown
4. Remove old drive and insert new
5. Mount array degraded in temp location
6. Double/triple check where your new drive enumerated to
7. Perform btrfs replace with new drive in the dead "slot" (btrfs missing device num)
8. Re-balance array to raid1 (metadata and data)
9. Reboot

Comment: In addition you may need to generate a new guide for the device

Comment: I'm simulating btrfs RAID1 failures in VirtualBox before spinning up metal with this setup. Removing and re-adding the disk resulted in the same: `sdb` reappearing as `sdc`, and unable to replace or even rebalance into `single`. Wipe, replace & reboot were enough to not end up in a grub rescue.